# Add custom text after each BBPress topic

Tags: bbpress

I am working on a functionality to add some custom text after each BBPress topic. I have tried following hooks with no luck:

`the_content`

`bbp_get_topic_content`

`bbp_get_reply_content`

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the content-single-topic.php *template*

Comment: I was looking for some kind of hook. Want to do this from a plugin.